# Получение координаты высоты ландшафта Three.js

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, three.js, 3d

Имеется рельеф в виде collada модели. Задача - добавлять другие модели на поверхность рельефа. Для этого нужно получить координату высоты рельефа в точке с заданными координатами x и z. Каким способом это можно сделать?

[изображение](https://pp.vk.me/c622717/v622717515/1aef5/5vn-UaAxowU.jpg)

Comment: @Антон Хавчиков, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);

if (intersects.length > 0) {
    console.log(intersects[0]); // .point.y
}
```

А создание `raycaster` вынесите в инициализацию:

```
raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
```